# asammdf export mf4 to csv

Tags: csv, mdf, asammdf

I have a .MF4 file and want to export a list of Channels to a CSV file.

Following is the function i used:

```
list.export(fmt='csv', filename='foo.csv',single_time_base=True, overwrite = True)
```

empty_channels are skipped by default [see documentation](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.export)

in the CSV i dont get any values for a specific Channel because there are multiple Signals with the same name. So he only find the empty channel and skips this.

How is it possible to get the Signal and add it to the CSV?

[image: i have the groupnumber and channelindex]

Answer (score 0):

Using the development branch code I get the expected result, since an unique name is generate in case of multiple occurrence. So you should see the following columns in the .csv output: "Sig", "Sig_0", "Sig_1" ...

```
from asammdf import MDF, Signal
import numpy as np

mdf = MDF()

mdf.append(Signal(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), name='Sig'))
mdf.append(Signal([], [], name='Sig'))
mdf.append(Signal(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1), np.arange(0, 10, 0.1), name='Sig'))

mdf.export(fmt='csv', filename='foo.csv', single_time_base=True, overwrite = True)
```

[image]